# Does adding redundant @JsonProperty value annotations to fields increase deserialization performance?

Tags: java, json, serialization, reflection, jackson

I'm using Jackson (2.6.0) to deserialize JSON requests into simple POJOs. I have implemented all the setter methods in my POJOs to fine tune the assignment. Some of the field names in the JSON are rather cryptic, such as `seq`. I'd like to name my java class field something like `layoutSequnce`.

I'm aware to do this I simply need to annotate my field as:

```
@JsonProperty("seq")
private int layoutSequence;
```

My question is for JSON fields I do not needto rename, such as `title`, is there any minimal performance advantage to annotating it anyway as:

```
@JsonProperty("title")
private String title;
```

My question stems from my understanding of how I think Jackson works behind the scenes. I'm assuming Jackson uses reflection to introspectively examine my POJO and identify the current field it's attempting to assign from the JSON value. With this approach, I'm assuming it has to do some searching to find a match, which has some small amount of overhead.

If I specify the field name directly, will Jackson just blindly attempt to initialize my field using a setter that matches the pattern of the field name (`setTitle()` in this example) I've identified in the annotation? Or does it still perform an internal class search to validate the method's existence?

Comment: This ought to be pretty straightforward for you to try out. My guess is this won't save you much time, since the annotation lookup likely has similar costs to the field lookup.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it should not improve performance. Introspection is only done once, to build the `JsonDeserializer`, and never after this initial time.
Annotation introspection (or even just general field, method introspection) is rather expensive operation, and so serializers/deserializers are aggressively cached to avoid having to do it more than once.

The only case where lookups would need to be repeated are when constructing a new `ObjectMapper`, that is, when not reusing/sharing small numbers (ideally one) of mappers.
`ObjectReader`s are different in that there is very little overhead, as they share cached deserializers with `ObjectMapper` that created them, so there is no need to reuse them. But mappers need to be reused.

Comment: This is insightful; I was not aware of this form of caching, thought it makes plenty of sense. Can you provide a bit more information on this topic (i've done a search and not seen anything really relevant)?

So the "cache" now contains exactly what? I guess my question still stand a bit beyond that. If one specified the "key" (in this case the field name to assign), wouldn't that be faster than searching the "values" (cached fields) to match the JSON field name?

Comment: For more information, perhaps join the jackson user or dev list. But in essence, serializers and deserializers are cached by the types they are used to handle, first time they are needed. Mapper will locate one it needs for "root value" (value directly given); and construction of serializers/deserializers will usually trigger recursive calls as well. Some of those calls will find serializer/deserializer already having been constructed. Bean(De)Serializer resolves property ser/deser eagerly as well.